# Matricez y botones en Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, vscode, programacion-asincrona

datos con nombres de usuario y demás, debo hacer al presionar siguiente aparezca el nombre que se encuentra en la matriz y si es anterior retroceda y muestre el nombre arriba de la imagen como se muestra en la imagen esto con los tres nombres que se encuentran en la matriz de javacript, mostrandolo en el orden de la matriz dada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

    <div class="conteiner">
                  <div class="conteiner-title">
            <span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="bottons">
            <!--BOTONES HTML-->
            <button" id="conteiner-button">
                ANTERIOR
            </button>   

            <button" id="conteiner-button">
                SIGUIENTE
            </button>

        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes inicializar el valor con el primer elemento y luego mediante la funcion siguiente y anterior controlar el nuevo indice y actualizar el valor.

```js
let user = [
    [1, 'juan'  ,  'red44'  ,  'juan@gmail.com'  ,  93485],
    [2, 'monica',  'coffe01',  'monica@gmail.com',  87533],
    [3, 'jose'  ,  'house02',  'jose@gmail.com'  ,  4555],

]

let currentIndex = 0;
let title = document.querySelector('#conteiner-text');
title.innerHTML = user[currentIndex][1];

function siguiente(){
    if(currentIndex < user.length-1){
      currentIndex++;
    }
    title.innerHTML = user[currentIndex][1];
}

function anterior(){
    if(currentIndex > 0){
      currentIndex--;
    }

    title.innerHTML = user[currentIndex][1];

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DOM</title>

    <!--FONTS-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desing.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/html.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="conteiner">
      
        <!--TITULO HTML-->
        <div class="conteiner-title">
            <span class="conteiner-text" id="conteiner-text">
                hola
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="bottons">
            <!--BOTONES HTML-->
            <button class="conteiner-button change_color" id="conteiner-button" onclick="anterior()">
                ANTERIOR
            </button>   

            <button class="conteiner-button change_color" id="conteiner-button" onclick="siguiente()">
                SIGUIENTE
            </button>

        </div>
        
    </div>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!, me sirvio demasiado